# java 6 total number of elements by group using entity / pojo class

Tags: java-8

I have a list, which is in List  values2.

```
 sdc-posistion-svc,SnakeYAML,2.1,OverDue
    sdc-event-generation-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Overdue
    sdc-event-subscription-svc,Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,Due in <= 90
    sdc-bh-registry-svc,Jettison - Json Stax implementation,1.5.3,Due in <=90
    sdc-event-generation-svc,Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,Due in >90
    sdc-posistion-svc,jackson-databind,2.14,OverDue
    sdc-event-subscription-svc,jackson-databind,2.14,Due in <= 90
    sdc-event-subscription-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Overdue
    sdc-posistion-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Due in <= 90
```

POJO class

```
public class CampRepost {

    private String serviceName;
    private String libName;
    private String  version;
    private byte[] status; ..
```

Created a POJO class CampRepost and add them to list

```
CampRepost cmpRepost = new CampRepost();
     List<CampRepost> campRepostList = new ArrayList<>();
     
     for(int i=0; i < values2.size(); i++) {
            String[] arrSplit = values2.get(i).split(",");
            cmpRepost.setServiceName(arrSplit[0]);
                cmpRepost.setLibName(arrSplit[1]);                  
                cmpRepost.setVersion(arrSplit[2]);
                cmpRepost.setStatus(arrSplit[3].getBytes());
        }
```

I want a consolidated report either by libName or ServiceName with total count by status

For example, SpringBoot has
total number of **Due in <= 90** is 1
total number of **Overdue** is 2
total number of **Due in >90** is 0

libName: SpringBoot, Due in <= 90 :1,Overdue:2,Due in >90:0

For example

1. if it is by **libname** then

   libName: SpringBoot, Due in <= 90 :1,Overdue:2,Due in >90:0
   libNmae: Apache Tomcat,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:0,Due in >90:1

2.if it is by **serviceName** then

```
  serviceName:sdc-posistion-svc,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:2,Due in >90:0 
    serviceName:sdc-event-subscription-svc,Due in <= 90:2,Overdue:1,Due in >90:0
```

How to do above consolidated report(like pivot table). I kind of struck. Any idea welcome

Comment: Is there any specific format in which you are trying to get the final data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would make some changes to the class.  There is nothing wrong with using setters to set the values during creation but a constructor would be cleaner.

```
class CampRepost {
    private String serviceName;
    private String libName;
    private String version;
    private byte[] status;

    CampRepost(String serviceName, String libName, String version,
            byte[] status) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.libName = libName;
        this.version = version;
        this.status = status;
    }
    // setters and getters here
```

Also, it is imperative that your status descriptions are consistent.  Having both `"Overdue"` and `"OverDue"` will treat both as unique in a map. Converting to a specific case would solve that problem but then spaces are also important.  So `"Due in <90"` vs `"Due in < 90"` would cause a similar problem.

If your data is huge you may want to create a map to deliminate spaces and convert to lowercase.  For example, `"Due in < 90"` could be converted to `"duein<90"` with the latter being used to create the map and then converting back when displaying the results.

The results are stored in a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>` where the outermap is the `lib name` or `service name` and the inner map holds that `status` and `count`.

Create the list using the aforementioned constructor

```
for (int i = 0; i < values2.size(); i++) {
    String[] arrSplit = values2.get(i).split(",");
    campRepostList.add(new CampRepost(arrSplit[0], arrSplit[1],
            arrSplit[2], arrSplit[3].getBytes()));
```

**Note:**  Not certain of the purpose of getting the bytes of the `status` string. I had to use the `String constructor` to convert back to a String when creating the maps.

To invoke the methods, do the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> results = genReport(campRepostList,
        CampRepost::getLibName); 
displayResults("libName", results);

System.out.println();

results = genReport(campRepostList, CampRepost::getServiceName); 
displayResults("serviceName", results);
```

prints

```
libName:Jettison - Json Stax implementation,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:0,Due in > 90:0
libName:jackson-databind,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:1,Due in > 90:0
libName:Apache Tomcat,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:0,Due in > 90:1
libName:SpringBoot,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:2,Due in > 90:0
libName:SnakeYAML,Due in <= 90:0,Overdue:1,Due in > 90:0

serviceName:sdc-event-generation-svc,Due in <= 90:0,Overdue:1,Due in > 90:1
serviceName:sdc-event-subscription-svc,Due in <= 90:2,Overdue:1,Due in > 90:0
serviceName:sdc-bh-registry-svc,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:0,Due in > 90:0
serviceName:sdc-posistion-svc,Due in <= 90:1,Overdue:2,Due in > 90:0
```

Here is one example of the alternative formatting.

```
displayResults2("serviceName", results);
```

prints

```
serviceName = sdc-event-generation-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   0
     status = Overdue       count =   1
     status = Due in > 90   count =   1
serviceName = sdc-event-subscription-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   2
     status = Overdue       count =   1
     status = Due in > 90   count =   0
serviceName = sdc-bh-registry-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   1
     status = Overdue       count =   0
     status = Due in > 90   count =   0
serviceName = sdc-posistion-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   1
     status = Overdue       count =   2
     status = Due in > 90   count =   0
```

Here is the method that computes the results.

- it takes the result map and the desired getter (lib or service).
- first, create a map to hold the results and populate with the `defaultStatusMap` as appropriate.
- then iterate over the `campRepostList` and adding the service if it doesn't exist and create the inner map with default values of 0. `LinkedHashMap` is used to preserve the order of the status fields. This is done using [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function))
- using [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) creates the status entry and increments the count for each encounter.

Initialized instance field to create `defaultStatusMap`

```
// created once
Map<String, Integer> defaultStatusMap = List
        .of( "Due in <= 90","Overdue", "Due in > 90").stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(st -> st, (value)-> 0, (a, b) -> a,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

This method and one for loop is used to gather the results.

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> genReport(
        List<CampRepost> campRepostList,
        Function<CampRepost, String> category) {


    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> results = new HashMap<>();

    for (CampRepost cr : campRepostList) {
        results.computeIfAbsent(category.apply(cr),
                v -> new LinkedHashMap<>(defaultMap))
                .merge(new String(cr.getStatus()), 1, Integer::sum);

    }
    return results;
}
```

This method displays the results as you specified in the question. It just iterates over each map's `entryset` and prints the values.

```
public void displayResults(String name, Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> results) {
    results.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.printf("%s:%s",name,e.getKey());
        for (Entry<String, Integer> e1 : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf(",%s:%s",e1.getKey(), e1.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }); 
}
```

This is a different display that displays the service or lib, then indents the each status on different lines.

```
public void displayResults2(String name, Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> results) {
    results.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(name + " = " + e.getKey());
        for (Entry<String, Integer> e1 : e.getValue().entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("     status = %-12s  count = %3d%n", e1.getKey(), e1.getValue());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error in  .merge(new String(cr.getStatus()), 1, Integer::sum);  Error is incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int  . In  Map.merge statement

Comment: @SeleniumNewbie I re-examined your question and checked my answer and it ran just fine. I would like to help but I don't know where the problem could be.  I will continue checking and try to force that error to see what would cause it but still permit the code to be compiled.

Comment: Can you please show me the complete stack trace?

Comment: Thanks, the error is cleared now. but count =   0 id did not sum up. all counts are 0

Comment: Thanks a lot displayresult2 is working fine. I was trying with displayresult.

Comment: but the count is worng , will work on this further. if you have any idea pls share. the output is like serviceName = sdc-position-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   0
     status = Overdue       count =   0
     status = Due in > 90   count =   0   status = 50   count =   3

Comment: the output like serviceName = sdc-event-generation-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   0
     status = Overdue       count =   0
     status = Due in > 90   count =   0
     status = 50   count =   4
serviceName = sdc-event-subscription-svc
     status = Due in <= 90  count =   0
     status = Overdue       count =   0
     status = Due in > 90   count =   0
 status = 50   count =   7
.Thanks a lot for the elaborate answers. I am making this an answer and try to solve the line status =50

Comment: @SeleniumNewbie Is the count correct on what I printed in my answer or am I computing the count wrong?

Comment: No No your count is correct. Due to some data inconsistent I got that status = 50 issue. Your code working like a charm. Once again thanks a lot for taking the time and share the code.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> lines = List.of(
            "sdc-posistion-svc,SnakeYAML,2.1,Overdue",
            "sdc-event-generation-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Overdue",
            "sdc-event-subscription-svc,Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,Due in <= 90",
            "sdc-bh-registry-svc,Jettison - Json Stax implementation,1.5.3,Due in <= 90",
            "sdc-event-generation-svc,Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,Due in > 90",
            "sdc-posistion-svc,jackson-databind,2.14,Overdue",
            "sdc-event-subscription-svc,jackson-databind,2.14,Due in <= 90",
            "sdc-event-subscription-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Overdue",
            "sdc-posistion-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Due in <= 90");

    List<CampRepost> data = parseData(lines);
    List<String> groupByLibName = convert(groupBy(CampRepost::getLibName, data));
    List<String> groupByServiceName = convert(groupBy(CampRepost::getServiceName, data));

    groupByLibName.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();

    groupByServiceName.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println();
}

public static Map<String, Map<String, Long>> groupBy(Function<CampRepost, String> classifier,
                                                     List<CampRepost> data) {
    return data.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier,
                                           Collectors.groupingBy(CampRepost::getStatus,
                                                                 Collectors.counting())));
}

public static List<CampRepost> parseData(List<String> lines) {
    return lines.stream()
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .map(parts -> CampRepost.builder()
                    .serviceName(parts[0])
                    .libName(parts[1])
                    .version(parts[2])
                    .status(parts[3])
                    .build())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static List<String> convert(Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map) {
    Set<String> statuses = getUniqueStatuses(map);

    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> Stream.concat(Stream.of("serviceName:" + entry.getKey()),
                                    statuses.stream()
                                            .map(status -> status + ':' + entry.getValue().getOrDefault(status, 0L)))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Set<String> getUniqueStatuses(Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .map(Map::keySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

@Getter
@Builder
public final class CampRepost {

    private final String serviceName;
    private final String libName;
    private final String version;
    private final String status;

}
```

**Output**

```
serviceName:Jettison - Json Stax implementation,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:0,Due in <= 90:1
serviceName:jackson-databind,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:1,Due in <= 90:1
serviceName:Apache Tomcat,Due in > 90:1,Overdue:0,Due in <= 90:1
serviceName:SpringBoot,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:2,Due in <= 90:1
serviceName:SnakeYAML,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:1,Due in <= 90:0

serviceName:sdc-event-generation-svc,Due in > 90:1,Overdue:1,Due in <= 90:0
serviceName:sdc-event-subscription-svc,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:1,Due in <= 90:2
serviceName:sdc-bh-registry-svc,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:0,Due in <= 90:1
serviceName:sdc-posistion-svc,Due in > 90:0,Overdue:2,Due in <= 90:1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 streams:**

You can use java 8 stream **`groupingBy`** feature in order to group the data.
Here you can group the data by any attribute like libName or serviceName.

***Grouping by libName:***

```
Map<String,List<CampRepost>> groupByLibName = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CampRepost::getLibName,
                                               Collectors.toList()));
```

**Note: **Here is the code for Specific format of output required:****

***Logic Here:***

Here, I have grouped the data using `libName` or `serviceName` and then iterate over the grouped data and for each grouped key,grouped the data again with the status attribute in order to count the value for each status and created a `StringBuilder` in a required format and then created a `List` of `String` as final output.

**Code for LibName:**

```
Map<String,List<CampRepost>> groupByLibName = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CampRepost::getLibName, 
                         Collectors.toList()));

        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

        groupByLibName.forEach((key, cList) -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("libName:" + key + ",");
            Map<String,Long> map =
                    cList.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CampRepost::getStatus,
                                     Collectors.counting()));
            sb.append("OverDue:" + map.getOrDefault("OverDue",0L)+ ",");
            sb.append("Due in <= 90:" + map.getOrDefault("Due in <= 90",0L) + ",");
            sb.append("Due in >90:" + map.getOrDefault("Due in >90",0L) + " ");
            output.add(sb.toString());
        });

        System.out.println(output);
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[libName:Apache Tomcat,OverDue:0,Due in <= 90:0,Due in >90:2 , 
 libName:SpringBoot,OverDue:2,Due in <= 90:1,Due in >90:0 ]
```

**Code for serviceName:**

```
Map<String,List<CampRepost>> groupByServiceName = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CampRepost::getServiceName, 
                           Collectors.toList()));

        List<String> output2 = new ArrayList<>();

        groupByServiceName.forEach((key, cList2) -> {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("serviceName:" + key + ",");
            Map<String,Long> map =
                    cList2.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CampRepost::getStatus,
                                    Collectors.counting()));
            sb.append("OverDue:" + map.getOrDefault("OverDue",0L)+ ",");
            sb.append("Due in <= 90:" + map.getOrDefault("Due in <= 90",0L) + ",");
            sb.append("Due in >90:" + map.getOrDefault("Due in >90",0L) + " ");
            output2.add(sb.toString());
        });
```

**Sample Output:**

```
[serviceName:sdc-event-generation-svc,OverDue:1,Due in <= 90:0,Due in >90:2 , 
 serviceName:sdc-posistion-svc,OverDue:1,Due in <= 90:1,Due in >90:0 ]
```